# In JSON created from a pydantic.BaseModel exclude Optional if not set

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I want to exclude all the Optional values that are not set when I create JSON. In this example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional


class Foo(BaseModel):
    x: int
    y: int = 42
    z: Optional[int]


print(Foo(x=3).json())
```

I get `{"x": 3, "y": 42, "z": null}`. But I would like to exclude `z`. Not because its value is `None`, but because it is Optional and there was no keyword argument for `z`. In the two cases below I would like to have `z` in the JSON.

```
Foo(x=1, z=None)
Foo(x=1, z=77)
```

If there is any other solution to set `z` to optional in this sense, I would like to see it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could exclude only optional model fields that unset by making of union of model fields that **are set** and those that **are not None**.

Pydantic provides the following arguments for exporting method [model.dict(...)](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict):

> `exclude_unset`: whether fields which were not explicitly set when creating the model should be excluded from the returned dictionary; default `False`.
>
> `exclude_none`: whether fields which are equal to `None` should be excluded from the returned dictionary; default `False`

To make union of two dicts we can use the expression `a = {**b, **c}` (values from `c` overwrites values from `b`). Note that since Python 3.9 it could be done just as `a = b | c`.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
from pydantic.json import pydantic_encoder
import json


class Foo(BaseModel):
    x: int
    y: int = 42
    z: Optional[int]

def exclude_optional_dict(model: BaseModel):
    return {**model.dict(exclude_unset=True), **model.dict(exclude_none=True)}

def exclude_optional_json(model: BaseModel):
    return json.dumps(exclude_optional_dict(model), default=pydantic_encoder)
    


print(exclude_optional_json(Foo(x=3)))  # {"x": 3, "y": 42}
print(exclude_optional_json(Foo(x=3, z=None)))  # {"x": 3, "z": null, "y": 42}
print(exclude_optional_json(Foo(x=3, z=77)))  # {"x": 3, "z": 77, "y": 42}
```

### Update

In order for the approach to work with nested models, we need to do a deep union( or merge) of two dictionaries, like so:

```
def union(source, destination):
    for key, value in source.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            node = destination.setdefault(key, {})
            union(value, node)
        else:
            destination[key] = value

    return destination

def exclude_optional_dict(model: BaseModel):
    return union(model.dict(exclude_unset=True), model.dict(exclude_none=True))

class Foo(BaseModel):
    x: int
    y: int = 42
    z: Optional[int]

class Bar(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: int = 52
    c: Optional[int]
    d: Foo


print(exclude_optional_json(Bar(a=4, d=Foo(x=3))))
print(exclude_optional_json(Bar(a=4, c=None, d=Foo(x=3, z=None))))
print(exclude_optional_json(Bar(a=4, c=78, d=Foo(x=3, z=77))))
```

```
{"a": 4, "b": 52, "d": {"x": 3, "y": 42}}
{"a": 4, "b": 52, "d": {"x": 3, "y": 42, "z": null}, "c": null}
{"a": 4, "b": 52, "c": 78, "d": {"x": 3, "y": 42, "z": 77}}
```

Comment: It is brilliant! I use other models in the main model, and it works on the whole structure fortunately.

Comment: Actually, no. First approach does not work if `None` is explicitly set for optional field of nested model, but I updated the answer for such cases.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using FastAPI then using `exclude_none` doesn't seem to work when a response_model is mentioned in the route decorator.

```py
@app.post("/items/", response_model=Item)
async def create_item(item: Item):
    return item.dict(exclude_none=True)
```

Fast api seems to reprocess the dict with the pydantic model

So overriding the dict method in the model itself should work

```py
def Item(BaseModel):
   name: str
   description: Optional[str]
   ...
   def dict(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        kwargs.pop('exclude_none', None)
        return super().dict(*args, exclude_none=True, **kwargs)
```

(an actual solution would put this definition in separate subclass of BaseModel for reuse)

Note: just changing the default value of the `exclude_none` keyword argument is not enough: it seems FastAPI always sends `exclude_none=False` as an argument.

---

Source: 
https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/3314#issuecomment-962932368